# Monotocity of Sequence with mathematical set

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hello the exercise is to define the monotonicity of sequence
$n^2 - 20n$, where $n \in \{1,2,3,...10\}$

I know there is a formula:

- $a_{n+1} − a_n >0$ sequence is growing
- $a_{n+1} − a_n <0$ sequence is decreasing
- $a_{n+1} − a_n =0$ sequence is constant

If i apply this formula to this exercise i get this (i get that function is not monotonic which is not true):**
[image]

**BUT if i just subsitute x and count (an) for each n i get that (it turns out to be decreasing)**
[image]

My question is: "Why formula I applied gets wrong answer"?

Comment: +1 for doing your work on the problem before asking the question and posting it. Made it easy to guide you properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying your formula yields
$$
\begin{split}
a_{n+1} - a_n
 &= (n+1)^2 - 20 (n+1) - n^2 + 20n \\
 &= (n+1)^2 - n^2 + 20n - 20 (n+1) \\
 &= 2n + 1 -20 \\
 &= 2n - 19,
\end{split}
$$
as you (correctly) concluded. Thus, as long $2n - 19 \ge 0 \iff n \ge 9.5 \iff n \ge 10$ (since $n$ is integral) you will have an increasing relationship.

As you correctly computed, $a_{10} = 10^2 - 20 \cdot 10 = -100$ and now
$$
a_{11} = 11^2 - 20 \cdot 11 = 121 - 220 = -99 > -100 = a_{10}
$$
and in fact the difference is exactly as you computed:
$$
a_{11} - a_{10} = 2\cdot 10 - 19 = 1
$$

---

Note the difference you were computing is $a_{n+1}-a_n$ so for the numbers you calculated by hand, e.g. the last pair, the result also holds:
$$
\begin{split}
a_{10} - a_9 = 2\cdot 9 - 19 = 18-19 = -1,
\end{split}
$$
which you can now confirm directly from your calculations...

Comment: Thanks for your answer!